# Set FSCalendarAppearance delegate in iOS Xamarin Native

Tags: ios, xamarin, calendar, delegates, fscalendar

Im trying to implement a calendar using FSCalendar for iOS.
https://github.com/MarcBruins/FSCalendar-Xamarin-iOS
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/fscalendar

I've got the calendar working but am unable to get enable appearance delegate methods (FSCalendarDelegateAppearance) in order to customise individual cells.

Also, though I am able to create CalendarAppearance object, I am unable to attach it to the calendar. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it, it can be done by setting

```
calendar.WeakDelegate = this;
```

and then using for both appearanceDelegate and delegate methods like

```
[Export("calendar:appearance:fillDefaultColorForDate:")]
        public UIColor FillDefaultColorForDate(FSCalendar calendar, FSCalendarAppearance appearance, NSDate date)
        {
            return UIColor.White;
        }
```